# Why BoundedVec does not implement a Decode trait

Tags: runtime, boundedvec, trait

A clear explanation will be appreciated as to why Decode trait is not implemented while encode is. What are the design reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

What? It is definetly decodable. Code from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/91d072df4273bbc04f8152099b23a66a0c1d531b/primitives/core/src/bounded/bounded_vec.rs#L279):

```rust
impl<T: Decode, S: Get<u32>> Decode for BoundedVec<T, S> {
    fn decode<I: codec::Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        let inner = Vec::<T>::decode(input)?;
        if inner.len() > S::get() as usize {
            return Err("BoundedVec exceeds its limit".into())
        }
        Ok(Self(inner, PhantomData))
    }

    fn skip<I: codec::Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<(), codec::Error> {
        Vec::<T>::skip(input)
    }
}
```

and a small test:

```rust
#[test]
fn encode_decode_works() {
    let bounded: BoundedVec<u32, ConstU32<7>> = bounded_vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let encoded = bounded.encode();
    let decoded: BoundedVec<u32, ConstU32<7>> = Decode::decode(&mut &encoded[..]).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(bounded, decoded);
}
```

Comment: I Guess not the trait `Decode` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::BoundedVec<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, u32>`